Graph API drive-id/root/delta endpoint returns ALL driveItems
When calling
sites/site-id/drives/drive-id/root/delta
It returns ALL contents of a Document Library/Drive and the next delta token.
When I thought it should return the immediate contents of the root and delta, not nested folders and files.
In the same way that:
sites/site-id/drives/drive-id/items/item-id/delta
Only returns its immediate children and its next delta token.
I need to get a delta for immediate children of the root.
Please can I have some help on how I can achieve this ?
Ideally I don't want to call the /children on the root every request as I would need to process all children regardless of changes or not.
I am using Application Permissions and Sites.Read.All

When you call the sites/site-id/drives/drive-id/root/delta endpoint, it indeed returns all contents of the drive, including nested folders and files, along with the next delta token. This behavior is by design, as the delta query is intended to provide a comprehensive snapshot of the drive's state, including all items.
To achieve your goal of getting only the immediate children of the root without needing to call the /children endpoint every time, you might consider the following approach:
Initial Delta Query: Start with the delta query to get all items in the drive. Store the @odata.deltaLink for future requests.
Subsequent Delta Queries: For subsequent calls, use the @odata.deltaLink to get changes. This will still return all items, but you can filter the results in your application logic to only process the immediate children of the root.
Optimize Processing: Since you are using Application Permissions and Sites.Read.All, you can implement logic in your application to track which items have already been processed and only act on new or changed items.
Unfortunately, the Graph API does not currently provide a direct way to limit the delta query to only immediate children of the root. Therefore, filtering on the client side after receiving the full list may be necessary.
